# Is there any way to split a Java String by first (or max) match using different delimiters

Tags: java, string, split

I need to split a String like ">=date" or ">date" preserving delimiter. I do as follows:

```
aString.split("(?<=>=|>)")
```

Java returns {">", "=date"}, capturing minimal matching delimiter, while I expect {">=", "date"}. Is there any way to force it to get first or max matching? maybe using apache or guava.
Thank you!

Comment: Here is ugly but proper one-liner aString.split("(?<=>(?!=)|>=)");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this regex in [here](http://regexr.com/3de38) and this is **Java** example :

```
String s = ">=date";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(>=?)(\\w+)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
matcher.find();

System.out.println(String.valueOf(matcher.group(1)));
System.out.println(String.valueOf(matcher.group(2)));

System.out.printf(" {\"%s\", \"%s\"}", matcher.group(1), matcher.group(2));

        //>=
        //date
        //{">=", "date"}
```

Comment: It is not a one-liner as I wished to get, but seems to be an answer. Thanks a lot from Saint Petersburg, Russia!

Answer (score 0):

Here I have set a example to split your `String` as per your expectation. [Demo here](https://ideone.com/KYk8SF)

```
    String aa = "date>=20,78+30<=date";
    String regex = "<=|>=|>|,|[/+]";
    String [] arr = aa.split(regex);
    for(String obj: arr)
    System.out.println("Result :"+obj);
```

OUTPUT Result is like

```
Result :date
Result :20
Result :78
Result :30
Result :date
```

Please try to build your own logic for your Code. It's just a demo over whatever u asked.
Thank You